# AccountManager return huawei account even if account have been signed out

Tags: android, android-studio, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-account

Android Version: 7 Huawei devices

AccountManager still returns account information after the user has been logged off. It should not return account information after it has been logged off.

> `accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.huawei.hwid")`

is there any alternative for getting active account info in Android?

Answer (score 1):

Sign out is to cancel the authorization. Actually, you do not log out.

The `getAccountsByType` interface in the Account-AdvancedSDK can obtain account information without authorization.

The two are not in the same SDK. You can use the signIn interface in the SDK to obtain account information.

Comment: actually, in the account section, there is no account present yet it returns an active account. Also, I am looking if there is an existing account or not. I just need the information but it is not for a login operation. is the sign interface the only solution. for this.

Comment: hi@Ashim Ghimire, Users and accounts do not refer to Huawei ID, but users on mobile phones. Huawei ID can only be registered on the HMS APK, and Huawei ID is not a user on a mobile phone.

Comment: hi, is it possible to check if there is an active Huawei ID signed in into the device for Huawei devices?

Comment: You cannot query whether a service is signed in. But you can call signIn to authorize the account and obtain the account information.